# How to send parameter?

Tags: javascript

How can I send image path to the function? My code is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addElement(this.id);" id="cricket" tabindex="1">Cricket</a>
```

I want to send my image path in the function `addElement` along with the `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addElement(this.id, this.getAttribute('href'));

Comment: but my problem is that when i write function function addElement(vlc,imgs){ var element=vlc; var element1=imgs; alert(element1); its not showing image but alerting image path..... please provide solution thanks....

Comment: That isn't the question you asked though.

Comment: can you explain to me what is image path??

Answer (score 0):

How the image path may be, are you defined the image path?

if you defined the image path, can workout like that

```
  <a href="#" onclick="addElement(this.id,'<?php echo "images/img.gif";?>');" id="cricket" tabindex="1">Cricket</a>
```

Comment: ya but how can i send image path without php tag

Comment: Provide striaghtly like that

<a href="#" onclick="addElement(this.id,'images/img.gif');" id="cricket" tabindex="1">Cricket</a>

Comment: but my problem is that when i write function
function addElement(vlc,imgs){
 var element=vlc;
 var element1=imgs;
 alert(element1);
its not showing image but alerting image path.....
please provide solution 
thanks....

Comment: If you alert a string, you get a string appearing in an alert window. You can't display images in an alert box.

Comment: how can you get the image in alert box? Only path rajesh. Now you are in right move. Proceed further.

Comment: I'll repeat: You **can't** display images in an alert box.

Comment: … and that isn't the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to do, but no, it is impossible to show an image in an alert window, the funcion window.alert() won't allow it in any possible way but not all is lost, if you wish to explore some alternatives you can try this link http://code.google.com/p/submodal/ which is a way to do something similar to what you seem to need, or you can try to use CSS to accomplish it if you're just trying to show an image.